# How to use ajax to post form data with non-UTF8 url-encoded string

Tags: javascript, firefox, character-encoding, greasemonkey

I'm writing a greasemonkey script to add some features to one webpage(so clearly I can't change the code of the server side).

This is a really old website which only receives GBK encoded string.
For example, the form in current webpage have a text input field filled up with value "中"(`\u4e2d`, `%E4%B8%AD` in UTF-8 byte stream, `%D6%D0` in GBK byte stream), when the user clicks the submit button, the browser will automatically serialize the form to application/x-www-form-urlencoded text then post it to the server. Because the webpage is claimed to be encoded in GBK, "中" is automatically encoded as `%D6D0%` in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded text, then the server side will decoded it with GBK encoding and get the right result.

Now I'm switching to ajax to submit the form to server(30~40 times in a short while), and I used JQuery's `serialize()` method to serialize the form to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` text, then posted it. The problem is, JQuery's serialize method eventually uses `encodeURIComponent` to encode all the values of the form, and at this time, "中" is encoded as `%E4%B8%AD` regardless of that the charset of current webpage is GBK. The server side still use GBK to decode it, then failed.

I have googled a lot about this, `encodeURIComponent` will always encode string as utf-8 stream, and in javascript language there is no utility functions can do what I want, which is get the serialized form data as the browser will automatically do.

Any ideas? thanks.

What about writing an firefox addons and use c/c++ code to implement a XPCOM to do the conversion from javascript string to GBK format url-encoded string?

Comment: You should be able to encode it yourself with javascript.  If [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16626362/331508) doesn't work, it should be pretty close.

Comment: @BrockAdams I have already tried that before I start up this thread. What that code really dose is to convert "%E4%B8%AD" to "中", or the other way around. What I need is convert "中" or "%E4%B8%AD" to "%D6%D0". The reason why that guy thought the conversion between "%E4%B8%AD" and "中" can be called conversion between UTF8 and GBK, is most probably he lacks the basic concept of javascript string and characterset knowledge. To convert a unicode charcode to a GBK charcode, I think there is no ways other than using a big mapping table.

Comment: I guess there is no way to do this with ajax, so I used iframe as the form's "target" to achieve my goals.