# Could html form specify the encoding of its target page?

Tags: html, character-encoding

I have a normal html `form` with the action to `http://another-site.com`.

My website(`http://my-site.com`) is encoded with `UTF-8`, but `another-site` is encoded with `GBK`.

The problem is, when I submit my `form` from `my-site.com`, and then the page forward to `another-site.com`, which is encoded with `GBK` as i mentioned. The page's characters are totally messy.

Is it my problem ? How do I tell the browser to use `GBK` in `another-site.com` ?

**NOTE** : Both `another-site.com` and `my-site.com` have set `content-type` with its encoding type.

Comment: you may want to check this out: 


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857295/how-to-use-ajax-to-post-form-data-with-non-utf8-url-encoded-string

Comment: You should not use domain names like another-site.com unless you mean a real domain with that name. For dummy examples, use URLs reserved for them, like example.com. It is often better to specify the relevant real URLs (to get real answers).

Comment: Please specify what you mean by “the page forward to...”. The server response to form submission may cause a redirect, but eventually it should result in an HTTP response that has its own information on character encoding.